# How to define sequence of execution in between two threads?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

Thread 1 prints A1 A2 A3. Thread 2 prints B1 B2 B3. I want to write a program that will make sure when both threads run the output will be A1 B1 A2 B2 A3 B3. So far I have come up with below program. Please let me know how this can be simplified?
Can we use less Semaphores?
Can this be achieved using wait() notify()?

```
package com.MultiThreading.threadSerialization;

import java.util.concurrent.Semaphore;

public class ThreadSerialization {

Semaphore a1Done = new Semaphore(0);
Semaphore b1Done = new Semaphore(0);
Semaphore a2Done = new Semaphore(0);
Semaphore b2Done = new Semaphore(0);
Semaphore a3Done = new Semaphore(0);

/**
 * methodA prints : A1 A2 A3
 */
public void methodA() {

    System.out.println("A1");
    a1Done.release();       
    b1Done.acquire();
    System.out.println("A2");
    a2Done.release();
    b2Done.acquire();       
    System.out.println("A3");
    a3Done.release();

}

/**
 * methodB prints : B1 B2 B3 
 */
public void methodB() {
    a1Done.acquire();
    System.out.println("B1");
    b1Done.release();
    a2Done.acquire();
    System.out.println("B2");
    b2Done.release();
    a3Done.acquire();       
    System.out.println("B3");


}

public void createTwoThreads() throws InterruptedException{ 
    ThreadSerialization ts = new ThreadSerialization();
    Thread T1 = new Thread(() -> ts.methodA());
    Thread T2 = new Thread(() -> ts.methodB());
    T1.start();
    T2.start();
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    System.out.println("test done");
}
```

}

Comment: Removed try catch for readability, though it won't compile without it.

Comment: Wrong approach. Please dont put up "not compiling" code. When people tell you: "your code is doing things the wrong way" - then ask how to fix that. And then fix it. Dont just blindly remove code. People will quickly jump on you for putting up not-compiling code.

Comment: Wasn't even that unclear in the first place, that's just Java boilerplate.

Comment: To get it to compile, enclose the body of each method in *one* try/catch block.  An interrupt is an explicit request for your thread to stop whatever it’s doing and exit gracefully.  You should never ignore InterruptedExceptions and continue as if nothing happened; doing so makes your thread a rogue thread that cannot be terminated cleanly.

Comment: @xTrollxDudex It was needlessly unclear and represented code that should either `throws` and/or wrapped at a higher level. Java doesn't force one to write code more complicated than Java requires.. just because Java IDEs want to "autowrap" checked exceptions doesn't mean they should be blindly honored :} I would have rejected such code under a review and it's extra important on SO where code in questions is judged much more quickly..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use two semaphore if you ensure that will only one thread executing `methodA` and another thread for `methodB`. When you print `A1`, you give `T2` the posibility to print `B1`. Then it will need to wait for `A2` to be printed to continue

```
  Semaphore aPrintDone = new Semaphore(0);
  Semaphore bPrintDone= new Semaphore(0);

/**
 * methodA prints : A1 A2 A3
 */
 public void methodA() {
     try {
         System.out.println("A1");
         aPrintDone.release();
         bPrintDone.acquire();
         System.out.println("A2");
         aPrintDone.release();
         bPrintDone.acquire();
         System.out.println("A3");
         aPrintDone.release();
    }catch (InterruptedException e1) {
         e1.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  /**
   * methodB prints : B1 B2 B3 
  */
  public void methodB() {
    try {
        aPrintDone.acquire();
        System.out.println("B1");
        bPrintDone.release();
        aPrintDone.acquire();
        System.out.println("B2");
        bPrintDone.release();
        System.out.println("B3");
    }catch (InterruptedException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This problem could also be resolved using `wait()` and `notify()`. Consider that `wait()` means that the thread will be waiting until a certain condition is met (in this case the B printing, for `T1`; and the A printing for thread `T2`). So when the `System.out.println` is done, it could `notify()` the other thread to start printing. I prefer the semaphore resolution, but it´s ok to solve it using those methods.

Comment: Great. This is working and number of Semaphores also reduced. Can you comment on if this can be done using wait-notify as well?

Comment: @AmolBinwade I updated my answer to cover the `wait-notify` question.

Answer (score -1):

To answer the `wait-notify` question: Yes, it is possible. It even works with only one lock-object. But the code is neither very readable nor "secure". The code requires, that `methodA()` is executed before `methodB()`, otherwise the program will deadlock.

```
public class Synchronization {

    synchronized public void methodA() {
        try {
            this.wait();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("A1");
        this.notify();

        try {
            this.wait();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("A2");
        this.notify();

        try {
            this.wait();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("A3");
        this.notify();
    }

    synchronized public void methodB() {
        this.notify();

        try {
            this.wait();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("B1");
        this.notify();

        try {
            this.wait();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("B2");
        this.notify();

        try {
            this.wait();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("B3");
    }

    public static void main(String... args) throws InterruptedException {
        Synchronization ts = new Synchronization();
        Thread t1 = new Thread(ts::methodA);
        Thread t2 = new Thread(ts::methodB);

        t1.start(); // If you switch those lines,
        t2.start(); // the program will deadlock.

        t1.join();
        t2.join();
        System.out.println("test done");
    }
}
```

Comment: If methodA executes first, the program will stuck because T1 will wait forever.

Comment: @AmolBinwade the first `wait()` in `methodA()` is released by the immediate `notify()` in `methodB()`. Can you please specify at which `wait()` you have seen a deadlock in `method1()`?

Comment: Right..i missed that...this should work...will give it a try and confirm. Thanks.

Comment: .But the sequence t1.start() before t2.start() doesn't guarantee that methodA will start execution before methodB. Its upto the scheduler which thread it will start executing first. Right?

Comment: That is true. this is why I explicitly said in my answer that `methodA()` has to be called before `methodB()`. You can enforcde the order through, e.g., a `CountDownLatch`.